# maven parent pom with the differnt child versions vs parent POM with the same child versions

Tags: maven

can any one let me know the exact difference between the parent pom with the different child versions and parent pom with same version in the child modules.

i was in confusion, is there any major tactic in this when we are going to multiple versions at module level.

1) let say parent module 1.0  and child modules are 2.0,3.o,.....
is there any problem?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience there are two cases when using parent POMs.

1. We just want to inherit basic configuration (plugin management, some basic libraries that are used from many projects (e.g. logging) etc).
2. We want to aggregate a set of modules as a multi-module project in order to build, test, release all the modules at once.

In the first case, it is reasonable that the parent POM may not be in the same version as its "children".
In the seconds case, we definitely want the parent POM version to be in synch with the version of its modules.